# how to hide GridView column when data is accessed dynamically in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hii

I have 2 gridviews they are bind by sqldatasource ,it contains Id , Name and Price

i dont want to show ID coloumn when page is loaded.How to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

Add Visible="false" to the column declaration, or in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void gvDocuments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the column from the code where you feel like.

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns["ID coloumn"].Visible = false;
```

Regards.